# Not all variables passed in POST

Tags: php, file, post

I'm working on a (supposedly) simple page and script to send an email with an attachment, but have run into a problem where the last value is not sent in POST. Danged if I can figure it out.

The HTML from the sending page is:

```
    <form action="contact_reply.php" method="post" name="form1"  required="required" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="PageURL" value="<?php echo GetSelfURL() ?>" />
  </p>
    <p>Your Name<br />
    <span id="sprytextfield1">
    <input name="MSG_Name" type="text"  required="required" id="MSG_Name" tabindex="1" size="70" maxlength="70" />
</span>
</p>

    <p>Your Email Address<br />
    <span id="sprytextfield2">
    <input name="MSG_Email" type="text"  required="required" id="MSG_Email" tabindex="2" size="70" maxlength="70" />
    </span>
    </p>

    <p>Subject<br />
    <span id="sprytextfield3">
    <input name="MSG_Subject" type="text"  required="required" id="MSG_Subject" tabindex="3" size="70" maxlength="70" />
    </span>
    </p>

    <p>Message<br />
    <span id="sprytextarea1">
    <textarea name="MSG_Text"  required="required" id="MSG_Text" cols="70" rows="5" tabindex="4"></textarea>
    </span>
</p>

    <?php
if ($Allow_Attachments)
{
?>            
    <p>Attachment (images only):
    <input name="MSG_Attachment" type="file" id="MSG_Attachment" tabindex="5" accept="image/*" multiple >
</p>
<?php
}
?> 
  <p align="center">
    <input 
    type="submit" 
  name="Contact_SendBtn" 
  id="Contact_SendBtn" 
  value="Submit" 
  tabindex="5"
  vakue="send"
    style="width:60px"/>
   </p>
</form>
```

The php on the receiving end is:

```
    function CheckMessageInfo()
{
global $MSG_Name, $MSG_Email, $MSG_Subject, $MSG_Text, $MSG_Attachment, $MSG_Error;

$MSG_Error = '';

echo "<p>".var_dump($_POST)."</p>"; 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
if (empty($_POST["MSG_Name"])) 
    {
  $MSG_Error .= "A name is required. ".PHP_EOL;
  } 
    else
    {
  $MSG_Name = test_input($_POST["MSG_Name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$MSG_Name)) 
        {
    $MSG_Error .= "Only letters and spaces are allowed in the name. ".PHP_EOL;
    }
    }

  if (empty($_POST["MSG_Email"])) 
    {
        $MSG_Error .= "An email address is required. ".PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
    $MSG_Email = test_input($_POST["MSG_Email"]);
    if (!filter_var($MSG_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        {
    $MSG_Error .= "Invalid email format. ".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

  if (empty($_POST["MSG_Subject"])) 
    {
        $MSG_Error .= "A subject for the message is required. ".PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        $MSG_Subject = filter_var($_POST["MSG_Subject"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

  if (empty($_POST["MSG_Text"])) 
    {
        $MSG_Error .= "The message's text is required. ".PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        $MSG_Text = filter_var($_POST["MSG_Text"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

    if (empty($_POST["MSG_Attachment"]))
    {
        $Allow_Attachments = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $MSG_Attachment = $_POST["MSG_Attachment"];
    }
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

The var_Dump line give me this:

```
array(6) {
  ["PageURL"]=> string(39) "www.vintagebankantiques.net/contact.php" 
  ["MSG_Name"]=> string(4) "Mike"
  ["MSG_Email"]=> string(21) "me@myemail.com" 
  ["MSG_Subject"]=> string(4) "test"
  ["MSG_Text"]=> string(21) "improved echo $_POST."
  ["Contact_SendBtn"]=> string(6) "Submit"
}
```

The "MSG_Attachment" variable is not listed. Where did it go?

Comment: Apparently on the sending side `$Allow_Attachments` is falsey (not set or empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value of MSG_Attachment by

```
$_FILES['MSG_Attachment']["tmp_name"]

//if MSG_Attachment is array type
$_FILES['MSG_Attachment']["tmp_name"][0]
$_FILES['MSG_Attachment']["tmp_name"][1]
```

since MSG_Attachment input type is file, you can not get in POST.

you can also refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)